# Mongoose .findOne() breaks when deployed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, vercel, vercel-micro

I have [Micro](https://github.com/zeit/micro) endpoints for my API that uses Mongoose. All of them work fine, except the one that uses .findOne(). This one returns the right data locally, but not when deployed to Now v2. Here is the endpoint:

```
const { createError, run, send } = require("micro");
const mongoose = require("mongoose").set("debug", true);
const mongooseConnect = require("./utils/mongooseConnect");
const Art = require("./schemas").art;
mongooseConnect();
const art = async (req, res) => {
  console.log("hello world");
  const id = req.url.split("id=")[1].split("&")[0];
  console.log("id", id);
  console.log("mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)", mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id));
  try {
    const data = await Art.findOne({ _id: id });
    console.log("data", data);
    if (!data) {
      throw createError(404, "Item of art not found.");
    }
    send(res, 200, { data });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    throw createError(error.statusCode, error.statusText);
  }
};
module.exports = (req, res) => run(req, res, art);
```

And here is the output:

```
2019-05-25T02:07:12.706Z  hello world
2019-05-25T02:07:12.706Z  id 5cb0a26bea66fa13786dc289
2019-05-25T02:07:12.707Z  mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id) 5cb0a26bea66fa13786dc289
2019-05-25T02:07:13.104Z  Mongoose: arts.findOne({ _id: ObjectId("5cb0a26bea66fa13786dc289") }, { projection: {} })
2019-05-25T02:07:13.173Z  data null
2019-05-25T02:07:13.174Z  { Error: Item of art not found.
                              at createError (/var/task/api/art.js:1584:14)
                              at art (/var/task/api/art.js:98943:13)
                              at <anonymous>
                              at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:228:7) statusCode: 404, originalError: undefined }
2019-05-25T02:07:13.175Z  Error
                              at createError (/var/task/api/art.js:1584:14)
                              at art (/var/task/api/art.js:98949:11)
                              at <anonymous>
                              at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:228:7)
04 MB 104 MB 104 MB 104 MB 104 MB 104 MB 104 MB 104 MB 104 MB 104 MB 104 MB 104 MB 104 MB 104 MB 104 MB 104 MB 104 MB 104 MB 104 MB 104 MB 104    MB 104 MB 104 MB 104 MB 104 MB 104 MB 104 MB
2019-05-25T02:07:32.932Z  running builder.exports.prepareCache...
2019-05-25T02:07:32.933Z  preparing cache ...
2019-05-25T02:07:32.937Z  producing cache file manifest ...
```

The weird thing to me is that I can see all documents of the `Art` schema in another endpoint (`const data = await Art.paginate();`). There, I see the document that should match

```
{
   _id: '5cb0a26bea66fa13786dc289',
   title: 'sdfsda'
}
```

Please let me know if any other details would help.

Comment: Have you tried `const data = await Art.findOne({ _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)) });`?

Comment: Yeah, I just tried that and the log is the same.